# MySQL hierarchical recursive query for fetch data

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider this is my table structure....

```
id | name        | parent_id
19 | category1   | 0
20 | category2   | 19
21 | category3   | 20
22 | category4   | 21
......
```

Now i want to fetch privious related rows with single mysql query. if i give `id=22' then query should return me id 21,20,19.

Also need to fetch (It can be a separate query) level wise data return. i.e. if i give id=22 then query should return only id 21 (first level). id 21,20 (secound level)...

Here's a similar [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)! 
Accept answer almost going to solve my problem but it only work assending order means when `parent_id < id`.

A portion of accepted answer :

```
select  id,
        name,
        parent_id 
from    (select * from products
         order by parent_id, id) products_sorted,
        (select @pv := '19') initialisation
where   find_in_set(parent_id, @pv)
and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id))
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  MySQL 8+ supports recursive CTEs.

Comment: I am using mysql  5.0.12 sir!

Comment: See "Alternative 2: Path-style Identifiers" in the answer from your link.

Comment: @MustaqueAhmed . . . Upgrade!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a stored function which will traverse the tree:

```
delimiter //
create function product_ancestors(in_id int) returns text reads sql data
begin
  declare current_id int default in_id;
  declare ancestor_ids text default null;

  while (current_id <> 0) do
    set current_id = (
      select parent_id
      from products
      where id = current_id
    );
    if (current_id <> 0)
      then set ancestor_ids = concat_ws(',', ancestor_ids, current_id);
    end if;
  end while;

  return ancestor_ids;
end //

delimiter ;
```

Use it with

```
select product_ancestors(22);
```

That will return a comma delimited string `'21,20,19'`.

See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2CuerGJhLApEKxgMjUmjjP/0)

Comment: i have no idea where to store this function and how can i run. Can you please give me some hints sir? i use phpmyadmin for mysql GUI.

Comment: @MustaqueAhmed In phpMyAdmin: Choose your DB. Click on "SQL" tab. Paste the first query.  Then click "OK". Use the function with `select product_ancestors(22);`

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the query from the link in your question by reversing things in it

```
select  id,
        name,
        parent_id, @pv 
from    (select * from products
         order by id desc) products_sorted,
        (select @pv := '21') initialisation
where   find_in_set(id, @pv)
and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', parent_id))
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=4f9f3a2a6189ee145db2be4d406ea8d6)

Answer (score -2):

In MySQL 8+, you can use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select c.id, c.parent_id
      from categories c
      where c.id = 22
      union all
      select cte.id, c.parent_id
      from cte join
           categories c
           on c.id = cte.parent_id
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Use a `join` to bring in the names, if you need them as well.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d9d7ddca1fab6eae485d5b16fbef3a4c) is a db<>fiddle.